# Using the "branch push" method of calculate "only: changes:" in pipeline event source - merge-request

Tags: gitlab-ci

The behaviour of "only: changes:" pipeline's rules in merge-request and in push branches event are different:

- During the push event changes calculates relative on previous commit.
- During the push in merge-request event changes calculates between the current branch and the target branch. (To tell the truth, if target branch is also a source branch, this is a not a HEAD commit of target branch, this is a merge-base commit - fork point or last merge commit with source branch )

So, if the branch have some code and some tests. Some stages relative from catalog of code, and test stages relative from test catalog. If I commit some changes of tests in branch having an merge-request event i expect run test stage only, but pipeline calculates changes relative target branch and it will be changes of tests, and as the code too. As result pipeline run all stages, include application build too, not only tests.

Is the way to solve this problem: calculate the changes like in branch push - from previous commit, instead of target branch?
An example below, i expect:
If no merge request: each commit into catalog "app/src" raise app building only. Also if some test may be placed in other catalogs and it will not raise any built or tests.
If merge request present: each commit into catalog "app/src" raise app building and run tests. Also, if some test changed outside catalog "app/src" it will raise tests only.

```
Stages:
    - build
    - test
build_job:
    stage: build
    script: 
        - echo App building
    only: 
        changes: 
        - app/src/**/* 
        variables:
        - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^dev\/.*/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
        - $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS == null && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push'
        - $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'web'
        - $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'api'

tests_job:
    stage: test
    script: 
        - echo App testing
    only: 
        variables:
        - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^dev\/.*/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

Comment: I thinked around this trouble and see no way, except the decline from using merge-request event at all and use the $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS variable to deside the run test, or no. But, AFAIK merge request event was invented for the testing, and it's a pity to decline it.
May be i skiped some thing in gitlab documentation and solution is exist.

Answer (score 1):

In GitLab 15.3 you can used `rules:changes` with [rules:changes:compare_to](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschangescompare_to) to compare a branch.

in your case:

```yaml
build_job:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - echo App building
  rules: 
    changes:
      paths:
        - app/src/**/*
      compare_to: 'main'
```

Comment: I.e. in my case i must use `compare_to: 'HEAD^'` ?  Because no branch for previous commit. We have only old 12.9 gitlab. So, good reason to upgrade. Thanck You!

Comment: Yesterday moved repo from old local gitlab to gitlab.com, there is version 15.5 and tryed use compare_to: HEAD^ in rules:changes:paths. There is no any errors, but it still no work :( -  the jobs include to pipeline even no changes in selected paths. May be it isn't work with HEAD^ reference?

Comment: I've made to set in compare_to: current commit, like:
`
    rules:
      - if: $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME == '~!Ref' && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS != null && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != 'push'
        changes:
          paths:
            - MPrjPath/src/**/*
          compare_to: '0dd4321c56b64a6dea8462be85a1e003a7a7c612'
`
 and I modifyed files in other directory, outside "MPrjPath", and jobs was not included in pipeline.

Comment: Is any branch can compare and it has a full name? like `main`,  `branch1`, or `refs/heads/branch1`. `compare_to` only supports branch name, tag name, and commit SHA.

Comment: No, it's just the previous (parent) commit of the current branch. I wrote about it in the question. So the one solution I see to this problem is to set in each successful pipeline a commit tag with a name similar to the branch name, and use that as the compare_to parameter in the next pipeline for that branch. It will be a little bit expensive - to much tag's as so many branches in project. Thank You anyway.